# Xterm get the max buffer size

Tags: c++, size, buffer, max, xterm

I'm trying to get the maximum buffer size who can accept a Xterm. I'm looking for something like GetLargestConsoleWindowSize under linux. I can't use curse.
Thanks.

Comment: It might be possible to get with some [xterm control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

Comment: I found this : "P s = 1 9 → Report the size of the screen in characters." But I don't really understand how use it i try this : std::cout << "\033[1;9t"; whitout sucess

Comment: Up ? I really need this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This and related escape sequences are normally disabled by the **allowWindowOps** resource setting.  You can set the resource or change the behavior at runtime using the *Allow Window Ops* menu entry (control/right/mouse menu).